# Socket IO not working with multiple node js servers

Tags: node.js, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 servers on AWS.

When

user A connects with server 1 and

user B connects with server 2

they are unable to join or chat. But if both connects with same server then they are joining successfully.

What would be the best way to handle this situations

Over the AWS, I am using Load Balancer with Auto Scaling.

Comment: Have you read this: [socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes](https://socket.io/docs/v3/using-multiple-nodes/index.html)? If so, what did you not understand about it? It appears to be designed for your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

From `socket.io`'s [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#passing-events-between-nodes):

> Now that you have multiple Socket.IO nodes accepting connections, if you want to broadcast events to everyone (or even everyone in a certain room) you’ll need some way of passing messages between processes or computers.
>
> The interface in charge of routing messages is what we call the Adapter. You can implement your own on top of the socket.io-adapter (by inheriting from it) or you can use the one we provide on top of Redis: socket.io-redis:

Implementing the Redis adaptor in our socket.io powered application for horizontal scaling is just a few lines of added code to the `index.js` file:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

To Enable AutoScaling in your application, add following line of code to the `scaling-policy.yml` file

```
# Enable autoscaling for the service
ScalableTarget:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  DependsOn: Service
  Properties:
    ServiceNamespace: 'ecs'
    ScalableDimension: 'ecs:service:DesiredCount'
    ResourceId:
      Fn::Join:
        - '/'
        - - service
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'ClusterName']]
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
    MinCapacity: 2
    MaxCapacity: 10
    RoleARN:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'AutoscalingRole']]

# Create scaling policies for the service
ScaleDownPolicy:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  DependsOn: ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    PolicyName:
      Fn::Join:
        - '/'
        - - scale
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
          - down
    PolicyType: StepScaling
    ResourceId:
      Fn::Join:
        - '/'
        - - service
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'ClusterName']]
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
    ScalableDimension: 'ecs:service:DesiredCount'
    ServiceNamespace: 'ecs'
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      AdjustmentType: 'ChangeInCapacity'
      StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalUpperBound: 0
          ScalingAdjustment: -1
      MetricAggregationType: 'Average'
      Cooldown: 60

ScaleUpPolicy:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  DependsOn: ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    PolicyName:
      Fn::Join:
        - '/'
        - - scale
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
          - up
    PolicyType: StepScaling
    ResourceId:
      Fn::Join:
        - '/'
        - - service
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'ClusterName']]
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
    ScalableDimension: 'ecs:service:DesiredCount'
    ServiceNamespace: 'ecs'
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      AdjustmentType: 'ChangeInCapacity'
      StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 0
          MetricIntervalUpperBound: 15
          ScalingAdjustment: 1
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 15
          MetricIntervalUpperBound: 25
          ScalingAdjustment: 2
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 25
          ScalingAdjustment: 3
      MetricAggregationType: 'Average'
      Cooldown: 60

# Create alarms to trigger these policies
LowCpuUsageAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmName:
      Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - low-cpu
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
    AlarmDescription:
      Fn::Join:
        - ' '
        - - "Low CPU utilization for service"
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
          - "in stack"
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
    MetricName: CPUUtilization
    Namespace: AWS/ECS
    Dimensions:
      - Name: ServiceName
        Value: !Ref 'ServiceName'
      - Name: ClusterName
        Value:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'ClusterName']]
    Statistic: Average
    Period: 60
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Threshold: 20
    ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref ScaleDownPolicy

HighCpuUsageAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmName:
      Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - high-cpu
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
    AlarmDescription:
      Fn::Join:
        - ' '
        - - "High CPU utilization for service"
          - !Ref 'ServiceName'
          - "in stack"
          - !Ref 'EnvironmentName'
    MetricName: CPUUtilization
    Namespace: AWS/ECS
    Dimensions:
      - Name: ServiceName
        Value: !Ref 'ServiceName'
      - Name: ClusterName
        Value:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Join [':', [!Ref 'EnvironmentName', 'ClusterName']]
    Statistic: Average
    Period: 60
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Threshold: 70
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref ScaleUpPolicy
```